# Convert Type Class to Table with Javascript in Enterprise Architect

Tags: javascript, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to convert a Class to a Table using Javascript.
When I execute the following code (assuming `currentElement` is an Element), the Stereotype of the Class updates to "table", in which updates to Stereotype "table" and takes on a blue-purplish colour when viewed. But, the Type does not update.

```
currentElement.Stereotype = "table"
currentElement.Type = "Table"
currentElement.Update();
```

When I select the updated element in the project browser, I still see that it is `Class : <name>`. How can I convert perform a Type conversion Class to Table using scripting (specifically Javascript)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table in EA is a stereotyped Class element, so you only need to change the stereotype.

When setting stereotypes in the API it is best to use only the `EA.Element.StereotypeEx` field.

The following code will successfully set the correct stereotype:

```
currentElement.StereotypeEx = "EAUML::table";
currentElement.Update();
```

Comment: Hehe. You copied Simon's answer ;-)

Comment: Not exactly, but yes, I compiled the answer from the responses on the forum, and my own experience.